# Summing array values over a specific range with numpy

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, scientific-computing

So I am trying to get the sum over a specific range of values in a text file using:

```
np.sum(d[a:b])
```

I am using a text file with 10000 entries. I know that we always start at zero. So my range is quite large i.e; index 200-555 (including 200 and 555). I tried just for testing summing over a small range:

```
In [17]: np.sum(d[1:4])
Out[17]: 50.164228
```

But the above code summed from the 2nd block (labeled number 1 by python) until the third. The numbers are; (0-> 13.024)
, 1-> 17.4529, 2-> 16.9382,      3-> 15.7731,( 4-> 11.7589), 5-> 14.5178.

zero is just for reference and it ignored the 4th-> 11.7589. Why?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/509211/8033585

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When using range indexing in Python, the second index (the 4 in your case) is not an inclusive index. By specifying `[1:4]`, you're summing the elements from index 1 up to *but not including* index 4. Specify 5 as the second index if you want to include the element at index 4.

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way apart from writing the next index like an operator? Like there is in C i.e >= when looping etc etc, but for the above operation again using np.sum?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you're asking if you can somehow specify "sum all elements with index i >= 1". To do that, just leave out the second index and specify the range like so: `[1:]`. This will sum all elements in the list except the one at index 0.